# Tomcat 7 doesn't "see" font file in pdf document

Tags: grails, tomcat7, font-face

I have a Grails web application which generates PDFdocuments after user buys something. When I start the application in GGTS everything works fine but when I deploy war file on Tomcat, letters Č and Ć aren't visible. PDF file does not render and I get null pointer exception.

This is the code: 
    @font-face {
    font-family: "DejaVu Sans";
        src:        url("${grailsApplication.config.fonts.folder}/fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf");
        -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed;
        -fs-pdf-font-encoding: Identity-H;
    }

I tried also with resource plugin and with google fonts but with no luck.
The above mentioned code works locally but on Tomcat/production not.

Please help.

Comment: Hi, do you have the stacktrace, or any other information about your problem? Seems like I have a similar problem, described here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33430972/rendering-pdf-not-working-on-prod-environment