# Rendering PDF not working on prod environment

Tags: pdf, grails

I have a very strange problem with rendering PDF working everywhere, but not on prod. Developer and test environments are working without problems, but prod just can't handle it. The only changes that are now on prod: higher Grails version than the last war (`2.1.0`->`2.3.8` [but this change has been introduced to the test environment ~2 months ago and all the problems were resolved then]) with few upgraded plugins, especially

```
compile ":rendering:0.4.3"
```

changed to

```
compile ":rendering:1.0.0"
```

Stacktrace I get on prod:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.xhtmlrenderer.swing.NaiveUserAgent.getBinaryResource(NaiveUserAgent.java:228)
at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver.importFontFaces(ITextFontResolver.java:97)
at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.setDocument(ITextRenderer.java:178)
at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.setDocument(ITextRenderer.java:142)
at grails.plugin.rendering.pdf.PdfRenderingService.doRender(PdfRenderingService.groovy:36)
at grails.plugin.rendering.RenderingService.render(RenderingService.groovy:43)
at grails.plugin.rendering.RenderingService.render(RenderingService.groovy:37)
at grails.plugin.rendering.RenderingService.render(RenderingService.groovy:35)
at grails.plugin.rendering.RenderingService.render(RenderingService.groovy:65)
at GrailsMelodyGrailsPlugin$_closure4_closure16_closure17.doCall(GrailsMelodyGrailsPlugin.groovy:184)
at RenderingGrailsPlugin$_closure3.doCall(RenderingGrailsPlugin.groovy:59)
at com.my.app.ReportController$_closure8.doCall(ReportController.groovy:169)
at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:200)
at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
at net.bull.javamelody.JspWrapper.invoke(JspWrapper.java:150)
at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$DelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:285)
at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:198)
at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:176)
```

My `ReportController` method for generating pdfs (nothing's really happening here and, yes, pdfShow file starts with an underscore):

```
    def generatePdf = {
    if (!params.id) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("PDF Generation: an instance identifier has not been passed.")
    }
    def reportInstance = Report.findById(params.id)
    renderPdf(template: "pdfShow", model: [reportInstance: reportInstance], filename: reportInstance?.reportFilename + '.pdf')
}
```

I have already done quite some research and found indications that it might be the problem with fonts declared in .css file which is used by the pdf template.

Well, this is the .css:

```
@font-face {
    src: url("../fonts/DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf");
    -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed;
    -fs-pdf-font-encoding: Identity-H;
}

@font-face {
    src: url(../fonts/DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold.ttf);
    -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed;
    -fs-pdf-font-encoding: Identity-H;
}

body {
    font-family: "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

And the fonts are there, both on test and prod. And did not change their location.

I have tried downgrading `rendering` plugin back to `0.4.3`, but it didn't work, complaining about not available classes:

```
plugins\rendering-0.4.3\grails-app\services\grails\plugin\rendering\document\XhtmlDocumentService.groovy: 20: unable to resolve class org.xhtmlrenderer.resource.XMLResource
(...)\plugin\rendering\pdf\PdfRenderingService.groovy: 25: unable to resolve class com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont
(...)\plugin\rendering\pdf\PdfRenderingService.groovy: 19: unable to resolve class org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer
...and few others etc.
```

setting in the `BuildConfig.groovy`

```
legacyResolve true
```

inside `grails.project.dependency.resolution { ...` also did not work.

Do you have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Have you tried running it in production without the `@font-face` sections in css?

Comment: @AshrafPurno not yet (I will), but what if I need this font and always used it without any problems?

Comment: Are there any CDNs or other caching mechanisms involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing which solved the problem, was adding one line to the `Config.groovy`:

```
environments {
    production {
        (...)
        grails.resources.processing.enabled = false
```

We had this line in the `test` and `development` environments, but before, with Grails 2.1.0 it worked anyway.

Comment: This didn't help me. I was forced not to use custom fonts as a quick fix...